# Overloading function templates in namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, function

Why does this fail to compile with GCC 4.4?

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void foo () {

    }

private:
    T x;
};

namespace Ns {
template<typename T>
void do_it (A<T> a) {
    a.foo ();
}
};

template<typename T>
void myfun (T x) {
    Ns::do_it (x);
}

template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    void bar () {

    }

private:
    T x;
};

namespace Ns {
template<typename T>
void do_it (B<T> b) {
    b.bar ();
}
};

int main () {
    A<int> a;
    B<int> b;

    myfun (a);
    myfun (b); // error: no matching function call to do_it(B<int>&)

    return 0;
}
```

It must have something to do with the namespace of `do_it`. When I remove the namespace around it, it compiles.

Background: I am building a set of functions that may be used with many different container classes. To handle the different interfaces uniformly I use freestanding functions that are overloaded for each of the container classes. These functions shall be put into a namespace to avoid cluttering the global namespace with them.

The definitions for B shall be thought of as coming from a different header file than those for A so reordering is not an option.

Comment: It is a typo! The <T> was swallowed by HTML.

Comment: VS 2010 compiles the above code, and I believe it is correct in doing so, but this is a tricky example. Nice question!

Comment: The same with VS2008, I just checked it. Could this be a bug in GCC or is their interpretation just different from Microsoft's? The fact that it works without a namespace would point to it being a bug, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that only ADL is done at the point of the call. Other function lookups are only done in the definition of the `myfun` function template.

And at that definition context, only the `do_it` overload accepting the `A<int>` is declared.

Edit: If you want to have a Standard reference for this, refer to [temp.dep.candidate] and [temp.res]p1.

Comment: @Mark if you want to have functions in namespace `Ns` considered, you can derive `B<T>` from a dummy class defined in that namespace, so that ADL will look into the `Ns` namespace. Or you can pass template arguments to `B<T>` that associate the generated specialization with `Ns`. For example `B<NS::ADLAssociator<int>>` (ADLAssociator could just be a small class template only storing `T t;`). Or you pass those associator classes as additional dummy arguments: `B<int, NS::ADL>`. There are many options for this one. The cleanest seems to be to just derive `B` from a class or define it in `NS`.

Comment: What about changing the free function into an static class member: `namespace Ns { template <typename T> struct dispatch; }` (declare it up front), then for each new type, add an specialization: `namespace Ns { template <typename T> struct dispatch < B<T> > { static void do_it( B<T> x ) { x.bar() } }; }`, and have `template <typename T> void myfunc( T t ) { Ns::dispatch<T>::do_it( t ); }`

Comment: @David yes that will work too, good idea. Won't depend on fragile ADL.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Could you please elaborate this answer? Especially the two phrases *"instantiation context"* and *"definition context"*? Are they standard terms used in the spec? :-/

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Also, first two suggestions of yours dont seem to work. (See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/658fa9cafd79f270) and [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f71d3dff25f043f4)) I didn't try the third one though.

Comment: @Nawaz for your second comment: You probably wanted to call `do_it(b)` instead of `myfun(b)`. ADL only works for `foo` not `qualifier :: foo`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Oops. Missed that. Thanks.